# Adding feature id column that autoincrements using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

Is there anyway to add the feature id column which increases automatically in attribute table programmatically? Here is a code to add a column:

```
fields = []
fields.append(QgsField('SOIL_ID', QVariant.Double))
vLayer.dataProvider().addAttributes(fields)
vLayer.updateFields()
```

But I want to add a column whose name is 'id' and it should increase in order without my touch.

Comment: I edit my question. There is the code to add the column. But I want to describe type for instance 'autoincrease' not 'double' or 'int'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to create a new field with incrementing values, you could try using the following:

```
vLayer = iface.activeLayer()

fields = []
fields.append(QgsField('ID', QVariant.Double))
vLayer.dataProvider().addAttributes(fields)
vLayer.updateFields()

i = 0
with edit(vLayer):  
    for feature in vLayer.getFeatures():
        feature.setAttribute(feature.fieldNameIndex('ID'), i)
        i += 1
```

---

*This worked in a previous 2.99 version I had installed. I just updated a few minutes ago and there is now an error when trying to open the Python Console - [Bug report posted](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/18050).*